# Why does Bash give "No such file or directory" for a program that's in my PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, path

I installed `docker-compose` on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine following the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/ to use `curl` to download the binary directly to `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
$ ls -lh /usr/local/bin/docker-compose 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16M Jul 11 15:55 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

`/usr/local/bin/` is in my PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/me/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Note that it comes before `/usr/bin`, in fact.

When I try to check its version, I get what seems to be a PATH-related error:

```
$ docker-compose --version
bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory
```

I get the correct behavior either by specifying the full path of the executable,

```
$ /usr/local/bin/docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
```

or by using `sudo`,

```
$ sudo docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
```

Why can't I run `$ docker-compose --version`?  Why does Bash complain about `/usr/bin` in particular, when it ought to find the executable in `/usr/local/bin`?

It might be relevant that I previously installed `docker-compose` via `apt`, but I have removed and purged this package.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Comment: Try `hash docker-compose`, explanation [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3371#issuecomment-381162525).

Comment: @harrymc That's exactly the problem and the solution.  Thanks!  And thanks for the link, I hadn't found that one.

Comment: Note that in such cases it is customary to ask the person who furnished the solution to also give the answer.

Comment: @harrymc Please do so and I'll accept it the answer.  I posted my answer based on a result from Reddit before I saw your comment.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have installed docker-compose once in one place.
Then you deleted it and installed it in another location.

In that way, you have run into an optimization of bash for not
having to search $PATH every time you type a command, by caching the results
in memory.
The path hash is a hash-table, maintained by bash, that contains the locations
on disk where the shell should look for executable programs when a command is run.
The hash table gets cleared on events that obviously invalidate the results (such as modifying $PATH), or by using the inbuilt `hash` command.

When you executed docker-compose again, bash just tried to get it from where it
found it the last time, only that it wasn't there any more, so you got that
error message.

To invalidate the hash for docker-compose, run the command:

```
 hash docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be an existing location entry from the previous installation, which `apt-get remove` and `apt-get purge` did not remove or purge.

`hash docker-compose` removes the entry.  More information can be found here:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3371#issuecomment-381162525
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82991/bash-is-not-finding-a-program-even-though-its-on-my-path

Answer (score 0):

After installing Docker using Snap, you removed docker from snap and installed without snap, but still the path points to the location /snap/bin/docker, so if you get this error, update the value of PATH to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I removed an existing docker using snap and installed the latest docker. And I see the same issue. I was tried to run "hash docker-compose", but my system can not find "hash" command. I just close my terminal and reopen another terminal, the problem disappeared.